# pyspark An error occurred while calling o23.jdbc. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, mariadb

I'm going to read tables from mariadb database using pyspark.And an error occur while running the below code
'''

```
jdbcHostname = "localhost"
jdbcDatabase = "pucsl"
jdbcPort = 3307
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mariadb://{0}:{1}/{2}?user={3}&password={4}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase, "root", "ravi")

df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="m00_02_lic_lic_reln",properties={"driver": 'com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Spark does not correctly recognize mariadb specific jdbc connect strings and so the jdbc:mysql syntax must be used. The followings shows a simple pyspark script to query the results from ColumnStore UM server columnstore_1 into a spark dataframe:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameReader, SQLContext
url = 'jdbc:mysql://columnstore_1:3306/test'
properties = {'user': 'root', 'driver': 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'}
sc = SparkContext("local", "ColumnStore Simple Query Demo")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = DataFrameReader(sqlContext).jdbc(url='%s' % url, table='results', properties=properties)
df.show()
```

p.s~ I believe you have successfully added MariaDB jar in place(Something like /spark3.1.2/lib/maridabjar...)

Comment: The fact the OP gets a _"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"_ indicates the JAR is not on the classpath.